# Binding data on cursor url not working on IE

Tags: css, angularjs, svg

I try to change cursor regarding user choice.
My div :

```
<svg id="{{ dirCtrl.id }}" name="{{ dirCtrl.cursorStyle }}"
            style="background-color: #A8A8A8; cursor: url({{ dirCtrl.cursorStyle }}), auto;"
            zoom="{{ dirCtrl.viewBox }}"
        > </svg>
```

This is working on chrome and FF, but not on IE (11). When i inspect code with console, I can see that i have the good value in my variable (in name=""). But the cursor style just disappear.
Here's the generated code :

```
 <svg class="ng-scope ng-binding" id="svg-container" style="background-color: rgb(168, 168, 168);" viewBox="0 0 640 480" ng-controller="WorkAreaViewController as viewController" zoom="0 0 640 480" name="Content/Images/Curseurs/Curseur.cur">
```

If i hardcode the cursor url like :

```
 <svg
            id="{{ dirCtrl.id }}" name="{{ dirCtrl.cursorStyle }}"
            style="background-color: #A8A8A8; cursor: url(Content/Images/Curseurs/Curseur.cur), auto;"
            zoom="{{ dirCtrl.viewBox }}"
        >
```

This is working, and i can see my custom cursors
Any idea?

Comment: try using `ng-style` instead.

Comment: That's it, thanks :)